# What does the comma operator do?

Tags: c++, c, operators, comma-operator

What does the following code do in C/C++?

```
if (blah(), 5) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Should specify the language in the question; I don't think tagging would be sufficient even if this didn't have both C and C++ tags.

Comment: @jfm3 not homework for me but someone in an IRC channel asked the question and i thought it was a good one
@Mark thanks, i noted the language in the question

Comment: "C/C++" is not a language. Most responders seem to focus on comma operator overloading, thus C++. The question should perhaps be re-tagged.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Comma operator is applied and the value 5 is used to determine the conditional's true/false.

It will execute blah() and get something back (presumably), then the comma operator is employed and 5 will be the only thing that is used to determine the true/false value for the expression.

---

Note that the , operator could be overloaded for the return type of the blah() function (which wasn't specified), making the result non-obvious.

Comment: Interestingly (at least to me), is that the ordering of operations evidently isn't ensured when you overload the comma operator.  In general, I don't think I'd ever do that though.

Comment: Reminds me of a bug I wrote a couple of days ago : wanted to write
CAnObject a( d, f ); but wound up writing CAnObject a = ( d, f );
Unfortunately there was a conversion from f's type to CAnObject. Awch.

Answer (score 45):

If the comma operator is not overloaded, the code is similar to this:

```
blah();
if (5) {
  // do something
}
```

If the comma operator is overloaded, the result will be based on that function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string blah()
{
    return "blah";
}

bool operator,(const string& key, const int& val) {
    return false;
}

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {

    if (blah(), 5) {
        cout << "if block";
    } else {
        cout << "else block";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

*(edited to show comma operator overloading scenario. thanks to David Pierre for commenting on this)*

Comment: No, C++ has operator, to take into account here

Comment: Yeah - forgot that you can override the comma operator in C++. I guess that's the real point of this question!

Answer (score 20):

I know one thing that this kind of code should do: it should get the coder fired. I would be quite a bit afraid to work next to someone who writes like this.

Answer (score 13):

In the pathological case, it depends on what the comma operator does...

```
class PlaceHolder
{
};

PlaceHolder Blah() { return PlaceHolder(); }

bool operator,(PlaceHolder, int) { return false; }

if (Blah(), 5)
{
    cout << "This will never run.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that depends on blah().

Comment: blah() will be called and we don't know the side effects.  So answering the question "what will this code do?" is not possible.

Comment: I agree with you, Ben.  There isn't enough info to say for sure.

Comment: for example, exceptions.  Or if you prefer c, goto.

Answer (score 1):

On a more broad answer. The comma operator (non overloaded)  resolves as in, execute the first part and return the second part.

So if you have (foo(),bar()) Both functions will be executed, but the value of the expression evaluates to bar() (and the type of the expression as well).

While I won't say there are fair usages for that, is  usually considered a bit hard to read code. Mainly because not many languages shares such constructs. So As a personal rule of thumb I avoid it unless I am adding code to a preexistent expression and don't want to change completely its format.

Example: I have a Macro (not discussing if you should use macros or not, sometimes its not even you that wrote it)

FIND_SOMETHING(X) (x>2) ? find_fruits(x) : find_houses(x)

And I usually use it in assignments like my_possession = FIND_SOMETHING(34);

Now I want to add log to it for debuggin purposes but I cannot change the find functions,. I could do :

FIND_SOMETHING(X) (x>2)? (LOG("looking for fruits"),find_fruits(x)):(LOG("looking for houses"),find_houses(x))

Answer (score 0):

The following was written assuming it is C code, either in a C file or within a C block of a C++ file:

It is a pointless *if*. It will call blah(), however the result of blah() is not considered by *if* at all. The only thing being considered is 5, thus the if will always evaluate to true. IOW you could write this code as

```
blah();
// do something
```

without any *if* at all.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately someone could have blah() return an object whose class had overloaded the comma operator and then who knows exactly what will happen.  The comma operator could compare something to the 5 and return false, skipping the code in the brackets completely.

Comment: If it is C++ at all (even a C++ project might have a plain C file among the list of files); there is a C++ tag, but also a C tag and this could be as well within a extern "C" block, in which case no overloading is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I use sometimes constructs like this for debugging purposes. When I force the if close to be true regardless of the return value of blah. 
It's obvious that it should never appear in production code.